# Php nowdoc (heredoc without parsing) is interpreting HTML Markup Characters - Not Desireable

Tags: php, heredoc, nowdoc

I have PHP that looks like this:

```
$func_code = <<<'EOT'
foo1
foo2 '<foo3>'. foo4 . '</div>';
EOT;

echo $func_code;
```

And the output looks like this:

```
one_half   
foo1 foo2 ''. foo4 . '';
foo1 foo2 ''. foo4 . '';
```

As you can see,  and  are both completely removed.  PHP docs claim that nowdoc won't parse anything inside the text block, but its obviously parsing the < and > symbols.

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: PHP isn't parsing it; your browser is. If you look at the source code of the page, you'll see that the HTML tags were outputted unchanged.

Comment: It’s probably just the browser you are viewing the output with that interprets the HTML.

Comment: Are you viewing this in a browser: if so, "view source"

Comment: HAHA!  I realized all this just before I checked back and saw all these answers.  LOL  Its always the little things that get me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't PHP who's parsing it. It's your browser. Check the page's source.

If you want the browser not to interpret these, send a `Content-type` header beforehand:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain'); //This should be placed before any output is sent!
```